# How do I reading stdin written by ssh remote with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, raspberry-pi3, stdin

I'm making a ssh-remote-and-real-time-controlled raspberry pi quadcopter.

Now I've encountered some problem about how to send data through ssh subprocess's stdin. Programming language is python3

What I want to achieve is I have a local python program which ssh-execute raspberry pi's quadcopter program as subprocess, and send user-command by writing it to that subprocess's stdin.
And my quadcopter should be able to receive user-command through stdin but does not block the whole program loop.

from my local controller program should be like

```
...
ssh_proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['python3','test.py'], # for now I'm using test py to debug
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
)

...
# when I send command
ssh_proc.stdin.writeline(my command)
```

and my receiver program for test:

```
import time
while (1):
    print('read from stdin', sys.stdin.readline(), flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

There should be some echo output for me to debug, but I got nothing.

Comment: try remove `stdout = subprocess.PIPE,` and `stderr = subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: also add `import sys` into your receiver program.